# Packer cant connect to a EC2 instance spun up inside a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer

Due to organizational restrictions all EC2 instances must be spun up inside a VPC. I am running Packer from an on prem server (via a Jenkins pipe) and during the image creation, it spins up an EC2 instance inside this VPC which is assigned a private IP.

Back on my on prem server, Packer is waiting for the instance to start up by querying the private IP assigned to it and there is no connectivity between the on prem Jenkins server and the EC2 instance spun up by Packer. Therefore the process hangs is stuck at `Waiting for WinRM to become available` forever.

Is there a workaround to this?

I am using the builder of type `amazon-ebs`

Comment: Do you have a VPN setup between on-prem and VPC?

Comment: @Marcin nope I do not. Will creating one do the trick? Two questions: I have to setup the VPN on AWS right? And how do I tell Packer to use the VPN?

Comment: I'm not using packer, can't help with that. Maybe regular ssh tunnel through a bastion host to the instance would be enough? But it all depends no what Packer requires.

Answer (score 1):

A bastion host on public subnet my help you in this case. You can find the Packer configuration for bastion host here: https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#communicator-configuration

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply... If possible could you please elaborate the use of a bastion host? What is its function?

Comment: would it be possible to share an example of a packer JSON that is using bastion host? I tried to find one but was unsuccessful so far.. Also I am trying to create a Windows AMI.. Hope the same is applicable

Comment: @user538578964 I'm not sure if bastion host works with Windows or not. I only tried with Linux. Please refer these keys:
`
ssh_bastion_host (string) - A bastion host to use for the actual SSH connection.
ssh_bastion_port (int) - The port of the bastion host. Defaults to 22.
ssh_bastion_agent_auth (bool) - If true, the local SSH agent will be used to authenticate with the bastion host. Defaults to false.
ssh_bastion_username (string) - The username to connect to the bastion host.
ssh_bastion_password (string) - The password to use to authenticate with the bastion host.
`

Comment: so what does a bastion host do exactly? Does Packer send commands through this bastion host to the temporary EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, bastion host is in public subnet. It's a 'jump' server for outside can access to instances in private subnet.

Comment: Understood.. That might work. I will try it out and let you know. One last thing, should Packer be installed on the Bastion host?

Comment: No, this is the common SSH property, not Packer feature.